# Permutation matrix to "invert" part of a matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, finite-fields

I am working with a Linear Code, C, over $F_{2^5}$, and its dual, $C^{\perp}$.  I have the generator matrix for $C$, $G$, and have calculated the generator matrix for $C^{\perp}$, $G^{\perp}$.  I need to find a permutation matrix $P$ such that $GP = G^{\perp}$.  I have determined that, if $G = (I_2\ |\ A)$, then $G^{\perp} = (I_2\ |\ A^{-1})$.  However, I have no idea how to invert only *part* of a matrix, and was hoping someone could get me started in the right direction.

This is a homework problem, so I am not asking for a solution or anything, I have just run out of ideas and was hoping for some new ones.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that you need to *invert* $A$ - transposing it will do. Let's first review the definitions. Most of this you probably know, but it also looks like some lingering confusions may be there.

If $G$ is a generator matrix for a code $C$, then $C$ is the row space of $G$, i.e. the span of the rows of $G$. For several good reasons we usually assume that the rows of $G$ are linearly independent. So if the length of your code is $n$ and the dimension (=number of information
symbols per block) is $k$, then $G$ is a $k\times n$ matrix with entries from your symbol alphabet $F_{32}$. What we often (but not always) do is to put this into a systematic form, i.e. we carry out some row operations on $G$, and, if necessary, permute some columns, and end up with
$$
G=(I_k | A),
$$
where $A$ is some matrix with $k$ rows and $(n-k)$ columns.

[Edit]
There is no such thing as *the* generator matrix of a code. There are several. Any matrix
that has the right rowspace will work. OTOH, if you use an error-correcting code for adding redundancy to transmitted/stored data, then you do have to select one, because you *encode* a message vector $m\in F_{32}^k$ as $x=Gm^T$, and selecting a different
generator matrix will change the encoding function. It doesn't matter as long as the transmitter and the receiver use the same $G$. The code $C$ = the set of vectors $x$ that comes out is the same for all generator matrices of $C$. Only the encoding "which $m$ corresponds to which $x$" depends on the choice of $G$.
[/Edit]

Then the dual code $C^\perp$ consists of vectors $y\in F_{32}^n$ with the property $yx^T=0$ for all the vectors $x\in C$. It suffice to check this for the rows of $G$.
In other words $y\in C^\perp$, iff $y G^T=0$. Standard linear algebra shows that the
dual code $C^\perp$ is an $(n-k)$-dimensional subspace of $F_{32}^n$ (the superscript $^T$
denotes the transpose here, so it is also a way of turning a row vector into a column vector).

Consider the matrix $H=(A^T| I_{n-k})$. It obviously has $n-k$ linearly independent rows.
Furthermore
$$
HG^T=(A^T)I_k+I_{n-k}A^T=A^T+A^T=0,
$$
because for any matrix $M$ over $F_{32}$ we have $M+M=2M=0$. This means that all the rows
of $H$ are vectors of the dual code $C^\perp$. Putting these bits together we see that $H$ is a generator matrix for the dual code.

So the shortest possible answer to your question is that the matrix $(A^T|I)$ is an answer. You may prefer to put this into a more standard systematic form with an identity block on the left. However,
there is no guarantee that we can do this by simply doing row operations on $H$ (if need be I will cook up a counterexample). When we put a generator matrix into a systematic form,
we must always be prepared to also permute the columns. This will change the code, but it will stay *equivalent* to the code we started with. So here we can simply swap the two blocks, and also say that $(I|A^T)$ is a generator matrix of a code that is equivalent to the dual code $C^\perp$.

In coding theory parlance it is standard to call the above matrix $H=(A^T|I_{n-k})$ the *parity check matrix* of the code $C$, because we can use that to check for membership in the code $C$. A vector $x\in F_{32}^n$ is an element of $C$, if and only if $Hx^T=0$. Here we use double-duality: $(C^\perp)^\perp=C$. So a parity check matrix of $C$ is a generator matrix of $C^\perp$ and vice versa.